# What does Csilla’s apology mean in the final scene of R.M.N.?

Tags: ending, r.m.n

Mungiu's excellent *R.M.N.* is a film that explores family relations and the topic of xenophobia.

In the final scene of the film, Csilla says "I'm sorry" to her friend. It's unclear what exactly she is apologizing for, and the film leaves it up to the viewer to interpret the meaning behind her words.

Was she sorry for leaving for Germany? Or, for (possibly) sleeping with the Frenchman? Or maybe, for not coming to dad's funeral?

Comment: "[T]he film leaves it up to the viewer to interpret the meaning behind her words", and that's a reason why this question is an ill fit here (and one of the beautiful aspects of many forms of art :).

Comment: pffffffffffffffff

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that Csilla and the Frenchman conspired.  The Frenchman was the one who gave the gun to Matthias.  Csilla later lured Matthias outside while he had the gun.  He started firing at a bear and ran after it.  As close as he was, he failed to hit the bear.  I think that they put blanks in his gun and got him out in the countryside where he was to be killed, probably by bears that the Frenchman managed to get there.  This is what Csilla was apologizing for - luring Matthias to his death.  But if I am correct, I am unclear why he was selected for such a fate with so many other townsfolk having similar views to Matthias'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s because Matthias is actually the one who threw the brick on fire through her window. If you notice, she claims to recognize the voice, saying it was Romanian with an accent. Matthias is one of the people throughout that we never nail down what his actual ethnicity is. Furthermore, how does Matthias magically pop up on her doorstep, moments after the brick is thrown? He would also be the person most concerned about other guys being in her household, and throwing a brick was the only way he could hide his identity and find out what was going on all at once.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  You're saying that _she_ apologised because _he_ threw a brick through her window?